# ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file

Tags: oracle, audit

I'm using Oracle 11.1.0.6.0 db, on Linux 64 bit server on Amazon cloud.

I'm getting following error when I run the connect command

```
SQL> connect / as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 30: Read-only file system
Additional information: 9925
ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 30: Read-only file system
Additional information: 9925
```

When I run this df -h command I'm not seeing the file system it's just showing as below

```
$ df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
```

I do not understand cause of this issue. Please let me know how to solve this issue

Comment: Seems that the filesystem on which the database is installed is readonly.?

Comment: Please update with output of `mount` (edit your question if possible)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
connect to SQL*Plus, then do:

```
show parameter audit_file_dest
```

then exit SQL*Plus and do:

```
cd <path displayed above>
ls -ld .
```

What are the permissions?  Ownership?

Perhaps a mounted filesystem has gone missing, and you don't have write permissions on the underlying mountpoint?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a Linux issue, not an Oracle issue. The simplest solution, if possible, it to reboot your system.

If this does not solve the problem, note if there is anything interesting in `/var/log/*`.

If this turns into a system-related or filesystem-related question, ask it at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or, if you find it more appropriate, on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Mind-bogglingly, after searching here and there this is the only solution to my similar problem -- When trying to recreate a database (after Oracle "forgot" which control files it has created), for a particular SID I kept getting audit trail file errors even though other SIDs are fine. Until I restarted.

Answer (score 1):

If the file system is missing then you haven't mounted it. You say that you are on Amazon, Have you created an S3 volume for your datafiles and software, or did you just use instance storage?

If the latter then the instance store is not persistent ([See this](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#What_is_the_difference_between_using_the_local_instance_store_and_Amazon_Elastic_Block_storage_for_the_root_device) for a related question).

If you have used an S3 volume is it presented to the vm and then mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Linux has an inbuilt mechanism to 'protect itself' when it detects hardware/os issues, hence the 'read only file system' message typically occurs when there are disk issues on the server in question and the server puts everything in read-only mode to protect against further corruption.